# Why does Kaspersky anti-virus prevent my program from capturing the output of its child process?

Tags: c#, windows

I have a C# program that launches a child process and captures its output in a string.  This works on most Windows machines (Windows 7 and newer), but when Kaspersky anti-virus is present, `Process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()` returns `null`.  There is no error code or exception.  The child process is a trusted console application.  The process takes 5 or 6 seconds to run.

The code for launching the child process is as follows:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
psi.FileName = "icao.exe";
psi.Arguments = im_path + "image.jpg";

Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = psi;

p.Start();

string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
string error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

MessageBox.Show(error);

p.WaitForExit();
int exitCode = p.ExitCode; 

MessageBox.Show(exitCode+"");
```

Why does `output` end up being `null` when Kaspersky is present?

Comment: Why did you tag this as C++?

Comment: because c# program execute dlib c++ example

Comment: It's a little hard to understand your question.  Are you saying that output and/or error are null when this program runs on a system with Kaspersky installed?

Comment: Yes it is. i checked both of programs and no signs of virus.

Comment: Exclude the executable from the AV, does it work then?

Comment: 1. Without antivirus works perfectly. if i reactivate anti virus and run programs return null. run after reactivate anti virus it never respond even antivirus activated or not. but both individually works on command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that Kaspersky's heuristics are seeing that your program wants to execute another exe. Because nothing is telling Kaspersky that this is ok, it flags your program as possible malware, because it wants to interface with other programs that are developed by other companies.  If you are able to I would try white listing your program with Kaspersky and see if that solves your issue.

Comment: external exe code - dlib.net/face_landmark_detection_ex.cpp.html